# Sample (and simple) postscript error file

Tags: printing

I need a small postscript file that causes a printer error to test an application I'm writing to help manage printer queues.  Rather than experiment with various combinations of postscript code to create one, I thought I'd ask if anyone has such a sample available.  I've googled to no avail and am turning to the ServerFault community as a last resort before I begin experimenting.

Also, it needs to error in such a way as to cause a printer error -- not be silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal PostScript file that **SHOULD** cause an error message '*/undefined in SHOW_*' or some such:

```
%!
200 500 moveto
/Helvetica findfont 36 scalefont setfont
(Hello, world!) SHOW_
showpage
```

Here is a PostScript file that should **NOT** cause an error (since the case sensitivity error of above file is corrected):

```
%!
200 500 moveto
/Helvetica findfont 36 scalefont setfont
(Hello, world!) show
showpage
```

Comment: This will cause a job error, but will it cause the printer to error out?  I need to get the printer into an error state.

Comment: Define "printer error out". (There are thousands of printer models; and there are thousands of possible reasons to make each model error out. Which particular combination do you want?)